# The meaning of & as function parameter in a compile error

Tags: c++, reference

I'm new to C++ and am trying to interpret what the compiler is telling me. I'm calling the function this way:

```
Object *clientConnection = new Object();
function(clientConnection);
```

and getting the following error:

> error: no matching function for call to 'function(Object*&)'

I'm trying to give a meaning to the following part `Object*&`. If I passed a pointer of the `Object` to the function what's with catch with the `&`?

Comment: What is the signature of `function`?

Comment: What's the entire signature of 'function'? That will probably help with this matter.

Comment: The `function()` is actually this `QObject::connect(const QObject * sender, PointerToMemberFunction signal, Functor functor)`. I've stripped it down to show just the part that i don't understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means you passed an lvalue of type `Object*`. If you passed an rvalue of type `Object*`, you would see a different error:

```
function(&*clientConnection);
```

should give

> error: no matching function for call to 'function(Object*)'

This information is part of the error message, because some functions can only be called with lvalues, and if you pass an rvalue, this lack of `&` points you towards the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You could implement `function(clientConnection)` in two ways

1. Call by value where the content of variable `clientConnection` will
   be copied in 'p'

   void function(Object* p)
2. Call by reference where 'p' is an alias of `clientConnection` in
   function body.

   void function(Object* &p)

When both of above definitions are missing, the compiler prints one of them mostly
`function(Object*&)`

Comment: What do you mean when you say `When both of above definitions are missing`. Missing in the function definition, or the call?